# Registering event, why the code can compile without error?

Tags: c#, inheritance, compiler-errors, event-handling, eventargs

I believe there should be many questions on SO related to this but I can't think of the proper keywords to search for them.

The code

```
class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber(Notifier n)
    {
        n.OnSomeEvent += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { }; //This does not compile
        n.OnSomeEvent += ReactOnEvent; //This compile successfully!
    }

    private void ReactOnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

class Notifier
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> OnSomeEvent;
    public void Trigger()
    {
        OnSomeEvent?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs());
    }
}

class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{

}
```

The compile errors for registering the lambda expression are making sense.

> Error  CS1661  Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'EventHandler<MyEventArgs>' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types
>
> Error  CS1678  Parameter 2 is declared as type 'System.EventArgs' but should be 'ConsoleApplication1.MyEventArgs'

But why compiler doesn't give me the same errors for this? Is my understanding of event handling fundamentally wrong? I think the compiler requires that the signature of the event and its handlers **are matching**.

```
n.OnSomeEvent += ReactOnEvent;
```

**Edit: The answer for this question**

As Peter pointed out in his comments, and quoted from [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegateshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates),

> (starting with .NET 3.5)...you can assign to delegates not only methods that have matching signatures, but also methods that return more derived types (covariance) or that accept parameters that have less derived types (contravariance) than that specified by the delegate type.

Answer (score -1):

when using a lambda expression the input parameters are inferred by the compiler.

n.OnSomeEvent += (sender, e) => { };

mouse over the sender and e, and you should notice that they have the correct types that are required for OnSomeEvent

A quick example about using lambda expressions to subscribe to events can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-use-lambda-expressions-outside-linq

Comment: Your answer is inapplicable to the question (because the OP's code doesn't use parameter type inference...he declares the lambda parameter types explicitly), and because you've failed to actually answer the question (your answer doesn't explain why anonymous methods are treated differently than named methods)

Comment: yes.. I write the code this way just to make it clear the types of the parameters are identical in the two approaches.

Comment: @kennyzx: no, you didn't write the code that way _just_ to make that clear. Had you not explicitly stated the parameter types, the anonymous method would have compiled just fine, obviating any need for your question in the first place. The crux of the problem in your code is that you are explicitly stating _incorrect_ types when there's no good reason to.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your explanation, I am more interested in why the 2nd line can compile successfully. Is my understanding of event handling fundamentally wrong? I think the compiler requires that the signature of the event and its handlers are matching.

Comment: @kennyzx: as described in the related specification language mentioned in the marked duplicates, and elsewhere in the documentation, C# supports variance for method group conversions to delegate types. The compiler requires that the delegate subscribed to the event matches, but it will allow a method with a compatible signature to be used to create that delegate instance, even if the types don't match exactly. See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you! Now I get it. I need some time to do some experiment.